# Whats to best way to verify a void method is called in spock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

Lets say I have a class `Foo` with two void methods `bar` and `biz(Object object)`

```
public class Foo {
  public void bar(){}
  public void biz(Object object){}
}
```

Both methods are complex methods with their own test cases but the problem is `bar()` calls `biz(Object object)` and I want to verify this in one of bar's test cases. So my test case is set up something like this in Spock.

```
class FooSpec {
  Foo foo = new Foo()
  
  def "test bar"() {
     given:
       boolean bizCalled = false
       foo.metaClass.biz = {Object object -> bizCalled = true}
     when:
       foo.bar()
     then:
       0 * _
     and:
       bizCalled
  }
}
```

I got this solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682050/spock-test-only-check-if-method-is-called-and-do-not-execute-it) the problem is that in this example `bizCalled` is always false causing the assertion to fail even though I've verified that `biz(Object object)` so `bizCalled` should be getting set to true.

Is there simply something wrong with the way I'm using metaClass or is there a more correct way in spock to verify that `bar()` calls `biz(Object object)` in Spock?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to make `FooSpec` extend `Specification` in order to really make it a Spock test. If you do that, the test passes. Here is your slightly adjusted and renamed original test:

```java
public class Foo {
  public void bar() { biz("dummy"); }
  public void biz(Object object) {}
}
```

```groovy
import spock.lang.Specification

class InternalMethodCallTest extends Specification {
  Foo foo = new Foo()

  def "bar calls biz"() {
    given:
    boolean bizCalled = false
    foo.metaClass.biz = { Object object -> bizCalled = true }

    when:
    foo.bar()

    then:
    0 * _

    and:
    bizCalled
  }
}
```

But that is not just ugly, it is also "un-spockish".  I suggest you simply use a `Spy` in order to verify internal method calls:

```groovy
import spock.lang.Specification

class InternalMethodCallTest extends Specification {
  Foo foo = Spy()

  def "bar calls biz"() {
    when:
    foo.bar()

    then:
    1 * foo.biz(_)
  }
}
```